# How to make 2 rigid body objects hit and stay together?

Tags: modeling

Usually, when an **active** rigid body object hits with a **passive** rigid body, it will collide and bounce off the passive one, base on physic.

But how to make the active rigid body object hits and stays / sticks with the passive rigid body?

My goal is to make a donut with chocolate scraps on top of it as topping. I tried to make this with **particles system**. The problem is the chocolate scraps will **intersect** with each other.

I found that many people suggested rigid body object as a workaround to this intersect particles problem. By making many rigid body objects that float in the air / above an object at frame 1, and let it falls and rests on the object to create the particle effect without intersection.

That would worked perfectly fine with flat object like a plane. But with my donut as in the screenshot, the scraps would bounced off as soon as it hits the donut. I wouldn't want that, I want it to stick with my donut as a topping.

[image: The screenshot shows my scraps setup in the air above my donut.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a lot of Friction to both the donut and the scraps.

Add rotational damping to the scraps.

On the scraps, choose Enable Deactivation and tweak the values (make them lot bigger).

Answer (score 0):

The parameter you´re looking for is located on the first particle system (you need either 2 separated particle systems to collide) or set an OBSTACLE and make it act as the particle "Sticky" object.

So on the object (or particle system) which you decide it´s going to stick, go to dynamics property tab (last tab on property panel to your right) and search for FRICTION and Stickiness. Notice I have enabled the tab COLLISION on the dynamic´s tab for **an object.** (the plane)
[image]

Thank you if you vote me up as the answer.

BFCT_Schiller